# imageview in a scrollview not zooming in some portion of view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i've implemented `imageview` zooming in `scrollview` application in my app.
i want to set the `scrollview` and `imageview` on the right top of the view. but it's not zooming there. when i placed it on centre of `view` it's zooming.

The code is given below

```
@interface przoomViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> 

{     
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView  *image;    
}

    -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView addSubview:image];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale=4.0;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 180)];
    scrollView.delegate=self;

}
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return image;
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should set value for `zoomScale` property of `scrollview` to start zooming as given below.

```
scrollView.zoomScale=1.0; // this will enable zooming.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented image zooming in my app. Try scrollviewDelegate Method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
  // The scroll view has zoomed, so we need to re-center the contents
  [self centerScrollViewContents];
}

- (void)centerScrollViewContents 
{
  CGSize boundsSize = zoomingScrollView.bounds.size;
  CGRect contentsFrame = ZImageView.frame;

  if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) 
  {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
  } 
  else 
  {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
  }

  if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) 
  {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
  } 
  else 
  {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
  }

  ZImageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}
```

No need to set userInterAction enabled on imageView. If this does not help, I will share my implementation.

Comment: setZoomEnabled property to yes of UIScrollView

Comment: there is not any property of setZoomEnable for scrollView

Comment: Yes you are right. Have a look at this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html